# Iterating SQL query inside python loop and changing the value of date function in SQL query with every loop

Tags: python, sql, vertica, vertica-python

I have a SQL query which I want to iterate using python for loop. Is there a way where I can define a variable inside the sql query and update it's value with each python loop?

`date1 = datetime.date(2017, 1, 1) date2 = datetime.date(2017, 12, 31) for d in daterange(date1, date2): SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE TABLE.CREATED_AT = '2017-01-01' cursor.execute(sql)`

I want to iterate through all the dates of year 2017(created_at). This is a sample problem, I can't use WHERE claus for date in my query as it is a complex query with lot of dependencies. Can some one help me regarding this?
I apologise in advance if there is any error as I am new to this platform and new to using sql using python.

Comment: I'm quite sure you **can** use `WHERE` , along with `BETWEEN` and `GROUP BY` in your query, and it's likely to be a lot more efficient doing so. Perhaps you should be asking about that instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. This is a sample problem written, my real code is 24 page long. It has multiple temp tables. The code actually goes to that particular date and perfrom insertion of data inside it.  The code works in a particular date window. All I can do is run it again and again for every date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the date in the format you indicated I would say that you should proceed in this way:

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
date2 = datetime.date(2017, 12, 31)
date_generated = [date1 + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (date2-date1).days)]

for date in date_generated:
   SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE TABLE.CREATED_AT = '{}';".format(date)
   cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Your solution was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. Please, accept and vote on the answer that helped you to close the topic. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You would better do it in SQL
However if you need to do it in Python here is one way:

```
for d in daterange(date1, date2): 
    SQL = f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE TABLE.CREATED_AT = {d}" 
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I've read up that this method is open to injections -- is this accurate?